# Passing variables into function on (valueChange) (TypeScript, Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and html, so I'm looking for help. I have this code:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (valueChange)="changeStatus(list.name, card.name)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let i of lists"> {{i.name}} </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

What I need to do, is to pass {{i.name}} (instead of list.name) into changeStatus() function.
Basically what happens, is when I choose option in drop-box, I want to pass option I chose into function. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks in advice

Comment: Mark my answer if it helped:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selectionChange` event with **[Template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)**  for it

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select #ref (selectionChange)="changeStatus(ref.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let i of lists" [value]="i"> {{i.name}} > </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**Component**

```
changeStatus(value)
{
console.log(value);
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxdeco-edjnzp)**

Comment: The value of ref.value is undefined

Comment: I have provided a working stackblitz? I did not the get issue you might be doing something wrong

Comment: could you Fork my stackblitz and reproduce the issue

Comment: I just followed your example in answer, I'm not sure whats wrong

Comment: That sounds quite strange it should not happen could you update your answer with rest of the code

Comment: I found the issue, I've added value into <mat-option>. The final result is:
<mat-option value ="{{i.name}}" *ngFor="let i of lists">. Thank you for help :)

Comment: Glad I could help:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **onSelectionChange** provided by MatSelect component and pass the **$event** variable.

Taken from the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api): `selectionChange: EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>`

MatSelectChange has two properties:

```
source: MatSelect
value: any
```

You have to change:

`<mat-select (valueChange)="changeStatus(list.name, card.name)">`

To:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
```

And on your **component.ts** you can handle the event like this:

```
onSelectionChange($event: MatSelectChange) {
    const list = $event.value; // const or let depending on your handle logic
    // Your logic here
}
```

**PS:** 80% of the times simple tasks that you look for in Angular Material are straight forward. Make sure you check the API + Examples so you can learn the "Angular Way" of doing stuff.

It is the actual purpose of Angular Material *"Our goal is to build a set of high-quality UI components built with Angular and TypeScript, following the Material Design spec. These components will serve as an example of how to write Angular code following best practices."*

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Yeah, I tried to search for mat-select, mat-option and mat-form docs, but did not find answers I was looking for.